# can a value be stored in variable returned by a function called as a parameter

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hi I was integrating facebook SDK in unity and basically I worked in java earlier and I am new to c# script and a question came to my mind.
I have searched a lot found nothing, may be my searching query is good enough or not but my question is ...

as a function FB.init called here

```
void Awake ()
{
   FB.Init(InitCallback, OnHideUnity);  
}
```

here when init function will be called it will call InitCallBack and OnHideUnity functions and both are returning void these are used form facebook-unity-sdk docs

```
private void InitCallback ()
{
    if (FB.IsInitialized) {
        // Signal an app activation App Event
        FB.ActivateApp();
        // Continue with Facebook SDK
        // ...
    } else {
        Debug.Log("Failed to Initialize the Facebook SDK");
     }
}

private void OnHideUnity (bool isGameShown)
{
    if (!isGameShown) {
        // Pause the game - we will need to hide
        Time.timeScale = 0;
    } else {
        // Resume the game - we're getting focus again
        Time.timeScale = 1;
    }
}
```

My question is if I call a function like this and that function return something e.g String and I want wanted to store it something like this

```
String result="";
SomeFunctions(FunctionOne,result=FunctionTwo);

 String FunctionTwo()
 {
  return "a String";
 }
```

Is this possible?
Is there any way to get value returned by such function call?
Or is this possible that a function that returns value can be called in this way?

Comment: Is `SomeFunctions` defined somewhere or do you define it? Seems you want an `out` parameter

Comment: are you actually passing function as parameter in function?

Comment: as you've seen about the OnUnityHide and InitCallBack both are function passed as parameters and i'ev test th've worked also all i want is that if a function like this returns something how can returned value will be stored

Comment: @FlatEric some function can be defined somwhere in a SDK or by my self

Comment: @FaheemAhmadKhan It seems like you are confusing a delegate for a function expression. The delegate will have no return value until it is invoked as a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are confusing a delegate for a function expression. The delegate will have no return value until it is invoked as a function.

```
void SomeFunction(Func<string> func) {
    var result = func(); // only here will the function return value be accessible
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
SomeFunction(() => "test");
```

Although you do not have access to the return value of the function, the delegate could assign a variable you choose inside it's method body, instead of using it's return value:

```
string result;
SomeFunction(() => {
    result = "test";
    return result;
});
// result would now contain "test"
```

Comment: @james-buckmes your right when i checked the definition of the functions provided in facebook-unity-sdk they were found delegates

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you want to achieve here, but you could use `out` to change the reference of the parameter.

```
string result="";

MyMethod(out result);

Debug.Log(string.Format("Result: {0}", result));

void MyMethod(out string pValue)
{
    pValue = "my changed value";
}
```

> The out keyword causes arguments to be passed by reference. This is like the ref keyword, except that ref requires that the variable be initialized before it is passed. To use an out parameter, both the method definition and the calling method must explicitly use the out keyword.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3c3bfhx.aspx

But in a case like this, you could just return the correct value. In the example below its not even worth passing the parameter since we are not using it.

```
string result = MyMethod(result);

string MyMethod(string pValue)
{
    pValue = "My changed value";
    return pValue;
}
```